# how to insert word by word in database

Tags: java, mysql, database, token

I'm having problems inserting data into a database after a tokenization process. I want to insert one by one word into database. I am using tokenization process to split the sentences. Below is my coding for tokenization process and inserting data:

```
      //tokenization process
      String speech = Report_tf.getText();
      System.out.println(speech);

      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(speech);
      while (st.hasMoreTokens()) 
          System.out.println(st.nextToken());

      //insert in database
      String token = st.nextToken(speech);    
      statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO laporan (text_laporan) VALUES ('"+ token +"')");
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for telling us. Let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: What do you run into?  Where is the rest of the code (orphan } at end)  I suspect you are missing a { after the while (st.hasMoreTokens()), but I don't know Java well enough to say for sure

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an opening brace on your while loop. That could be the problem. I'd be surprised if this even compiles.

Comment: i'm not missing brace.. there are no error but the data cannot insert in database

Comment: Well, if you cut and pasted that code, you are missing a brace. Clearly it is missing in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Start with something like this:

```
String speech = Report_tf.getText();
String [] tokens = speech.split("\\s");

for (int x=0; x < tokens.length; x++) {
  System.out.println(tokens[x]);
  statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO laporan (text_laporan) VALUES ('"+ tokens[x] +"')");
}
```

Comment: Try connection.commit(); and see if that helps. Also try to execute your update manually to see if you have any errors (like misspelled table of column name). Also, you may have an issue with words that contain ' in them (ex.: "can't").